# how to use haru?

Tags: using, libharu

can anyone help me on how to use libharu. i already downloaded libharu and am trying to run their sample demo in dev-c++ environment but the errors a raises. this is the error message: `C:\DOCUME~1\ITCPIA~1\LOCALS~1\Temp/ccUDbaaa.o(.text+0x6d):text_demo.c: undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_SetRGBStroke'`

Answer (score 0):

An undefined reference when linking means that you've forgotten to link against the proper library. Either add it to your references, or add `-lharu` to the command line, or whatever your development tool of choice requires for libraries.

Comment: The manual for your development tool of choice will explain how.